# When is it important to use the plural of "system?"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

When would **system** need to be pluralized?

Say you offer two products that serve the same function. Do you offer two systems or one system?

To try and give an example...

I have an integrated facial recognition system built into the camera. Few years passed and I developed a new camera that also has my facial recognition. I offer both options. Would I say:

"My system integrates facial recognition..." or "My systems integrate facial recognition..."

Is there a rule for determining something like this? By sound I lean towards it being a singular system. My colleague believes it needs to be plural.

Comment: You uses system when you have just one of them, and systems when you have more than one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it could turn out to be a marketing answer (i.e. how do you want it to sound?)

- an *old system* and a *new system* make *two systems*.
- If the underlying code is basically the same, you could say it's the same system (but you may not want to in the interest of selling the new product)
- If the product is the system (rather than containing it), and you offer two products, you offer two systems (by definition).

Don't forget that a system is a set of interoperable parts, so two independent sets leads to two systems.  So I tend to agree with your colleague in this case.

It's not really grammatical number IMO, more logical number, though I agree with the choice of tag.